# how do you get a variable from a post address in zendframework 1

Tags: zend-framework, post

I am still new to Zend Framework and confused about a few concepts.

I have built a POST form and attached a unique **Id** to the URL at the end of the form. I now want to collect that Id when the form is submitted but I am unclear how to do that

I will show you want I have done:

Below is the function that renders the form from my controller page to the view. You will note that I have fed into the parameter, for the form, a return Action address with the ID

```
 $action = "{$this->view->baseUrl()}/sample-manager/process-price/{$sampleId}";
 $this->view->Form = $model=  $this->_model->createForm($action);
```

The function to receive the post is below. However, I want to collect the Id that should have come back with the post return values, but I have no idea where to find it or how to attach it.

```
public function processPriceAction()   
 {
   $this->requirePost();  

  if($this->_model->processTieredPriceForm($this->view->form, $this->getRequest()->getPost()))
  {
   $this->_helper->FlashMessenger('Changes saved');

   return $this->_redirect("/product-ecommerce/{$this->_model->getProduct()->id}");
  }
  else
  {
   return $this->render('index');
  }
 }
```

In summary, when a post is returned, does the return address come with the post in Zend Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not supply the id into the construction of the form and assign it to a hidden element? For example, in your controller:

```
$action = "{$this->view->baseUrl()}/sample-manager/process-price";
$this->view->Form = $model=  $this->_model->createForm($action, $sampleId);
```

In your form model (not provided so best guess here):

```
$sampleId = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('sampleId');
$sampleId->setValue($sampleId);
$form->addElement($sampleId);
```

Then once the form is posted, you should be able to get the sample id in your controller in the standard way:

```
$sampleId = $this->getParam('sampleId');
```

Comment: thank you Tim and Ashley. i appreciate the assistance given on this matter. warm regards Andreea

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends a bit on how your routing is setup. If you're using the default setup, after the action name the default route allows for key/value pairs of additional data. So, you might have more luck with a URL like this:

```
{$this->view->baseUrl()}/sample-manager/process-price/id/{$sampleId}
```

That'll put your sampleId in a named parameter called 'id', which you can access in your controller action with `$this->_getParam('id')`.